# Can pure functions read global state?

Tags: multicore, global-state

Please note: by a "pure" function, I don't mean "pure virtual"
I'm referring to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

If a function "reads" some global state, does that automatically render it impure? or does it depend on other factors?

If it automatically renders it impure, please explain why.

If it depends on other factors, please explain what are they.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A "pure" function is a function whose result depends *only* on its input arguments. If it reads anything else, it is not a pure function.

Comment: And It has no side effect. You could have a function whose result depends only on its input arguments but it changes a global variable, so it is not a pure function.

Answer (score 4):

In certain specialized instances, yes.  For example, if you had a global cache of already-computed values that was only read and written by your function, it would still be mathematically pure, in the sense that the output only depended on the inputs, but it wouldn't be pure in the strictest sense.  For example:

```
static int cache[256] = {0};
int compute_something(uint8_t input)
{
    if(cache[input] == 0)
        cache[input] = (perform expensive computation on input that won't return 0);
    return cache[input];
}
```

In this case, so long as no other function touches the global `cache`, it's still a mathematically pure function, even though it technically depends on external global state.  However, this state is just a performance optimization -- it would still perform the same computation without it, just more slowly.

Comment: uh, wouldn't you still be able to get "same input, different output" from such a function.  For example bit flipping, it reads a cache of booleans and returns the opposite of what is there, and flips it at the same time.  Then when the function is run with the same "input", it would get different outputs (depending on past usage of the function).  That function cannot be pure.

Answer (score 0):

> Pure functions are required to construct pure expressions. Constant expressions are pure by definition.

So, if your global 'state' doesn't change you are fine.

Also see [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)):

> A more subtle example is that of a function that uses a global variable (or a dynamically scoped variable, or a lexical closure) to help it compute its results. Since this variable is not passed as a parameter but can be altered, the results of subsequent calls to the function can differ even if the parameters are identical. (In pure functional programming, destructive assignment is not allowed; thus a function that uses global (or dynamically scoped) variables is still referentially transparent, since these variables cannot change.)

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell for instance, you can create an endless list of random numbers on the impure side, and pass that list to your pure function. The implementation will generate the next number your pure function is using only when it needs it, but the function is still pure.